# python ArgumentParser - error: unrecognized arguments: ip_2 '127.0.0.1'`

Tags: python

I have the following code in a python script.

```
parser.add_argument('ip_1', default="127.0.0.1", nargs="?",
                     help="The First IP address.")
parser.add_argument('ip_2', default="127.0.0.1", nargs="?",
                        help="The Second IP address")
parser.add_argument('--port', type=int,
                    help=port_1")
```

I am executing the script from pycharm. I have specified the following `script parameters` in `PyCharm Run/Debug Configurations`

`ip_1 '127.200.300.400'   ip_2 '127.0.0.1' --port_1=4444`

I get the following error.

`test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: ip_2 '127.0.0.1'`

What am I doing wrong here.?

Comment: Try taking out `ip_1` and `ip_2`. The parser will (I think) assign your given IP addresses to those automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For argparse, if the first argument (`dest`) does not have a prefix character (`-`) it will be treated simply as a positional argument.  So in actuality with the arguments supplied, `parser.ip_1` will be `'ip_1'` and `parser.ip_2` will be `'127.200.300.400'`.  The rest of the argument will simply be treated as an error as they are unexpected.  Simply omit the strings `ip_1` and `ip_2` for the script parameters (and also supply `--port=4444` instead of `--port_1`) will do what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:
The only solution was to enter the following in Pycharm on the Parameters line in Edit Configurations tab

```
-o file.csv
```

If I omit the `-o` I get the error. Quotations around the filename are optional.

**Background**:
I had the same problem using Argparse and Python 3.7

```
parser.add_argument("-o", "--outfile",
                help="Enter the name of a .csv file to contain output or default of radarOutTemp.csv will be used",
                default="radarOutTemp.csv")
```