# error: unrecognized arguments (pycharm)

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to run code using user's args as:

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Script for running daily batch jobs for T3000 Project')
    parser.add_argument("from_date", help='date in  string yyyy-mm-dd', default='2017-10-1')
    parser.add_argument("to_date", help='date in  string yyyy-mm-dd', default='2017-12-31')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(
        from_date=args.from_date,
        to_date=args.to_date
    )
```

While passing the arguments, I am following the path in Pycharm as: `Run->Edit Configurations->Script Parameters: "2017-10-31" "2017-11-1"`

I am getting error:

```
driver.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 2017-10-31 2017-11-1

Process finished with exit code 2
```

I have seen the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906822/python-argumentparser-error-unrecognized-arguments-ip-2-127-0-0-1), which seems similar to my problem, but given solution didn't work for me. I am missing something I guess. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first argument parser:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args = parser.parse_args()
```

is expecting no arguments, but you have passed in two. That is where the complaint is coming from. The solution is simply to remove those two lines - I don't know why you have them there in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand the comment by @lxop, I had the same error but I require both these lines. My code is the same apart from variables as the code used in the original question.

The solution for me is to set up my parameter in Pycharm as follows, quotations around the parameter are optional. I get the error when -o is missing.

```
    -o filename.csv
```

My argparse setup line is

```
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--outfile",
                        help="Enter the name of a .csv file to contain output or default of radarOutTemp.csv will be used",
                        default="radarOutTemp.csv")
```